# How often have advanced degrees been revoked due to misbehavior as an undergrad?

Tags: masters, postdocs, undergraduate, plagiarism, cheating

Has anyone ever lost their PH.D. or MA from something they did when they were an undergrad?
I'm going to use an example of a college buddy who has an MA in history but bullshitted a project once as a sophomore.  They did a presentation on an event that they didn't actually go to.  What would happen if that was found out?

I thought about this after reading several articles. It appears that when individuals lose their advanced degrees, they typically do so because of plagiarism related to their thesis or falsifying data in a study.  In other words, things they did in their post graduate years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the criteria for degree revocation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/what-are-the-criteria-for-degree-revocation)

Comment: You might be hard pressed to find somebody who _didn't_ "bullshit" some project as an undergrad. Just the way it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not entirely impossible, and it may have happened a time or two, it would be extremely unusual for a graduate degree to be rescinded for an activity that happened in undergraduate years. The person would have passed a lot of milestones since then.

A lot of undergraduate misbehavior is handled within the institution and sanctions applied, but almost always the details are kept private to the institution, even when known. And academic misconduct, rather than actual serious crimes, are typically handled as an internal matter.

I doubt that the scenario you describe would be treated as serious enough, if discovered much later, to even rescind the bachelor's degree.

Occasionally, a degree will be rescinded later when the person commits some serious crime (pedophilia) or the actual process of obtaining that degree is questioned (plagiarism). The former case is due to the fact that the association between the institution and the individual reflects badly on the institution. The latter situation is because the degree was obtained fraudulently.

But both of those are pretty rare. Honorary degrees, as opposed to earned degrees, are probably the more common situation, when the individual "honored" commits some public deed generally considered horrendous. Think Jeffrey Epstein, though I don't know if he is an example.