# Can someone’s degree get revoked if the university has evidence they cheated retrospectively?

Tags: university, cheating, degree, canada, medicine

I know someone who got caught stealing the exam and cheating.
He now practices and sees patients!
If I alert the universities to look into it they will see that my information is correct. Will they be still allowed to see and treat patients?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this person cheated when getting the degree they hold? It sounds like you are describing someone who i) cheated in the past and ii) did not admit to cheating in a future interview, but not someone who cheated while working on the degree they actually hold.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify this because it sounds like all you have actual evidence for is old cheating, on a course which the person did not graduate from.

Comment: You seem to have information that no one but the person themself would be likely to have. You seem to have details of their application to the foreign U. You seem to know what they were asked in interviews and how they answered. How is it that you could know all these things with enough certainty to avoid a lawsuit? Skeptical.

Comment: A libel lawsuit, actually, from the subject of your accusations.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/what-are-the-criteria-for-degree-revocation Does this answer your question?

Comment: What you "know" and your "certainty" aren't a defense in a libel suit. And, again, _how_ do you know these things if you aren't the subject?

Comment: If they "got caught", then it seems like either (1) the resulting investigation did not convict him, or (2) the resulting investigation convicted him and imposed sanctions, but the university ultimately awarded the degree anyway. Either way, it sounds like the degree was correctly awarded and there is nothing to do here. It might be different you could prove that the person cheated and was never caught.

Answer (score -2):

This has happened before in many instances.  For example,

https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/feb/09/german-education-minister-quits-phd-plagiarism